# How to convert specific text from a list into uppercase?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I want to make uppercase all driver names that are from countries starting with "`United`".

For example:

From

```
20  [United Kingdom] Nigel Mansell                 188 31
```

to

```
20  [United Kingdom] NIGEL MANSELL                 188 31
```

The command that I am using:

```
cat f1.txt | sed -r 's/[^ ]"United"\s+[A-Z]+[a-z]*]\s+[A-Z]+[a-z]*\s+[A-Z]+[a-z]*-?[A-Z]?+[a-z]?*/\U&/g'
```

Full list:

```
Rank Country         Driver                      Races Wins
1   [United Kingdom] Lewis Hamilton                264 94
3   [Spain] Fernando Alonso                        311 32
8   [United Kingdom] Jenson Button                 306 15
11  [Netherlands] Max Verstappen                   116 9
17  [United Kingdom] David Coulthard               246 13
20  [United Kingdom] Nigel Mansell                 188 31
26  [United Kingdom] Jackie Stewart                100 27
27  [United Kingdom] Damon Hill                    115 22
28  [Spain] Carlos Sainz Jr.                       115 0
32  [United Kingdom] Graham Hill                   177 14
37  [United Kingdom] Jim Clark                     72  25
38  [Poland] Robert Kubica                         97  1
41  [South Africa] Jody Scheckter                  112 10
42  [New Zealand] Denny Hulme                      112 8
47  [Switzerland] Clay Regazzoni                   131 5
49  [Sweden] Ronnie Peterson                       123 10
50  [New Zealand] Bruce McLaren                    102 4
51  [Russian Federation] Daniil Kvyat              107 0
52  [United Kingdom] Eddie Irvine                  147 4
54  [United Kingdom] Stirling Moss                 72  16
58  [United Kingdom] John Surtees                  111 6
59  [United States] Mario Andretti                 128 12
60  [United Kingdom] James Hunt                    92  10
63  [United Kingdom] John Watson                   152 5
64  [Thailand] Alexander Albon                     35  0
69  [United States] Dan Gurney                     86  4
71  [United Kingdom] Mike Hawthorn                 48  3
76  [United Kingdom] Lando Norris                  35  0
78  [United Kingdom] Paul di Resta                 59  0
80  [United States] Richie Ginther                 52  1
85  [United States] Phil Hill                      51  3
86  [United Kingdom] Martin Brundle                158 0
87  [United Kingdom] Johnny Herbert                161 3
89  [Sweden] Stefan Johansson                      79  0
90  [New Zealand] Chris Amon                       97  0
94  [United Kingdom] Tony Brooks                   41  6
95  [Venezuela] Pastor Maldonado                   95  1
99  [United Kingdom] Derek Warwick                 147 0
100 [United States] Eddie Cheever                  132 0
101 [Switzerland] Jo Siffert                       97  2
103 [Russian Federation] Vitaly Petrov             57  0
104 [United Kingdom] Peter Revson                  30  2
113 [United Kingdom] Peter Collins                 36  3
114 [United Kingdom] Innes Ireland                 52  1
119 [Sweden] Jo Bonnier                            106 1
120 [Spain] Pedro de la Rosa                       105 0
124 [United Kingdom] Mark Blundell                 61  0
125 [United States] Harry Schell                   63  0
127 [Sweden] Gunnar Nilsson                        31  1
128 [Spain] Jaime Alguersuari                      46  0
130 [United States] Jim Rathmann                   12  1
132 [United Kingdom] Mike Hailwood                 51  0
133 [Switzerland] Sebastien Buemi                  55  0
135 [United Kingdom] Mike Spence                   36  0
136 [South Africa] Tony Maggs                      26  0
140 [United States] Masten Gregory                 40  0
142 [United States] Sam Hanks                      9   1
143 [United Kingdom] Piers Courage                 27  0
145 [United States] Bill Vukovich                  5   2
147 [United Kingdom] Tom Pryce                     42  0
148 [United Kingdom] Roy Salvadori                 48  0
149 [United States] Jimmy Bryan                    9   1
153 [Sweden] Marcus Ericsson                       97  0
159 [Switzerland] Marc Surer                       82  0
160 [Netherlands] Jos Verstappen                   106 0
161 [United Kingdom] Stuart Lewis-Evans            14  0
167 [United Kingdom] Mike Parkes                   6   0
168 [United States] Rodger Ward                    12  1
174 [United Kingdom] Jonathan Palmer               84  0
176 [Sweden] Reine Wisell                          23  0
179 [United Kingdom] Jackie Oliver                 50  0
180 [United States] Johnnie Parsons                10  1
181 [United Kingdom] Peter Arundell                13  0
185 [United States] Tony Bettenhausen              13  0
186 [United Kingdom] Cliff Allison                 16  0
187 [United Kingdom] Richard Attwood               17  0
188 [United Kingdom] Peter Gethin                  30  1
191 [Switzerland] Rudi Fischer                     7   0
192 [United States] Johnny Thomson                 9   0
194 [New Zealand] Howden Ganley                    36  0
199 [United States] Troy Ruttman                   8   1
200 [United States] Lee Wallard                    2   1
```

Comment: Your code is trying to match `sed -r '..."United"...` - look at how many `"`s your input has around `United`. Repeat for everything else you're trying to match with your regexp vs whats actually present in your input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are overdoing it, take advantage of your file structure to keep it simple!

If we find the string `[United` in a line, uppercasing everything from the closing brace to the end of the line gives the result you are after. Translating this into Sed language,

```
sed '/\[United/s/].*/\U&/' file
```

Note that the above is specific to GNU Sed. If not available but in a POSIX system, you can use [Ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) (or see [αғsнιη's Awk version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626516)) with a similar syntax:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/\[United/s/].*/\U&/' '%p' | ex file
```

To save the changes to the file instead of printing the results, change `%p` to `x`.

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F"[][]" '$2 ~/^United/ { $2="["$2"]"; $3=toupper($3); }1' OFS='' infile
```

within `[...]` we defined both `]` and `[` as field separator then checking against the second field if that start with `United` text, if yes then add back `[]` around second filed (I assume there is no other column inclining these characters, else those fields will miss this); then we convert third column to its uppercase value; the idiom `1` is trigger `awk` default print (a kind of always true condition).

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` we can do it by first determining the position of the closing square bracket in the current record when that record has United in its 2nd field.

```
$ awk '
    $2 == "[United" {
      p = match($0, /]/)
      $0 = substr($0, 1, p-1) \
        toupper(substr($0, p))
    }1
' f1.txt
```

Posixly sed can do it along the same lines as the awk solution. We need to get the]  position and mark it so that tge pattern space is divided into two halves. Tge right half has the name and on it we uppercase it by means of the y/// command.

```
$ sed -e "
    /\[United[[:blank:]]/!b
   y/]/\n/
    h;s/.*\n//
    y/$(printf %s {a..z})/$(printf %s {A..Z})/
    x;s/\n.*//
    G
    y/\n/]/
" f1.txt
```

```
$ perl -pe 's/\[United\s+.*?]\K(.*)/\U$1/' f1.txt
```